# Compact sets and open coverings

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ and when we have to prove that $Y$ is compact should we always find sets that are open in $Y$ covering it and that has a finite sub collection or it is okay also to consider sets open in $X$? To put the question in another way should compactness be checked based on sets that are open in THAT space?

Comment: Munkres *Topology* p. 165:  Lemma 5.1  Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$.  Then $Y$ is compact iff every covering of $Y$ by sets open in $X$ contains a finite subcollection covering $Y$

Comment: It may be worth noting if $A$ is open in $Y$ there does exist an open $B$ in $X$ so that $A\subset B$.  So if you have a cover $U_{\alpha}$ so that all $U_k$ or open in $Y$ there an open cover $W_\alpha$ where $U_k\subset W_k$ and $W_k$ is open in $X$ (even if $U_k$ is not open in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose that for any cover of $Y$ by open sets in $X$ there is a finite subcover. Then $Y$ is compact.

*Proof* : Consider a cover $\mathcal U$ of $Y$ by open sets in $Y$. Then, there is a family $\mathcal U'$ of open sets in $X$ such that $\mathcal U = \{Y \cap U : U \in \mathcal U'\}$. Observe that $Y \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal U = Y \cap \big( \bigcup \mathcal U' \big) \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal U'$, which means that $\mathcal U'$ is a cover of $Y$ by open sets in $X$. Thus, there is a finite subcover $\mathcal V'$ of $\mathcal U'$, and then $\mathcal V := \{Y \cap U : U \in \mathcal V'\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal U$. Hence, $Y$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the compactness of $Y$ is about collections of open subsets of $Y$, as you say.

However, what is an open subset of $Y$? By the definition of the subspace topology, it is a set of the form $U \cap Y$ for some $U$ which is open in $X$.

This means that we get the result described by @J.W.Tanner and @azif00, which says basically that it doesn't matter whether we look at open subsets of $Y$ or open subsets of $X$.