# To what extent is compactness inherited by subspaces?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In Valter Moretti's "[Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8847028345)," Remark 4.2 (1), he claims:

> Compactness is hereditary, in the sense that it is passed on to induced topologies.

I am not sure exactly what he means by this. In particular, one might interpret this in the most strong/general sense possible:

> Let $(X,\mathcal T_X)$ be a topological space, and $(A,\mathcal T_A$) be a subspace, i.e., $A \subseteq X$ and $\mathcal T_A$ is the induced topology from $\mathcal T_X$. Let $K⊆ X$ be compact. Then $K\cap A$ is compact in $(A,\mathcal T_A)$.

Is this true? Please explain why or why not.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899840/compact-sets-and-open-coverings)

Comment: Note that, while false in general, this is true when $A$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: I don't have the text in front of me, but I recall that the cited section describes compact operators.  Compactness of operators may well be hereditary...

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, but this remark was introductory and concerned general topology only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author probably means that compactness is inherent property of subspace: you don't need the space in which it is contained to deduce its compactness.

In more rigorous terms. Let $ (X, \, \tau_X)$ be a topological space. Consider its compact subspace $ K \subset X $. Then for any $ Y $ such that $ K \subset Y \subset X $ with topology $ \tau_Y $ induced from $ X $, $K$ as subspace of $ Y $ is also compact.

In particularly, when $ Y = K $ space $K$ is compact in $K$ itself. What does it mean? Consider a collection of open sets $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ with $\forall \alpha:\: U_{\alpha} \subset K $ that covers $K \subset \bigcup_{\alpha}U_{\alpha} $, or as everything is contained in $K$ we have $K = \bigcup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$. Then we have a finite subcover: $K = \bigcup_{i=1}^{N} U_i $.

It is easily proved by using the definition of subspace topology. For $ Y \subset X $ $\tau_Y$ is defined by the map $ i\ :\ Y \to X $. The set $U \subset Y $ is open, iff $\exists V \subset X $ such that $ U = i^{-1}(V)$. In other words $i$ is an open map (it maps open sets to open sets). Thus we can push any open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ in $Y $ to open cover $\{f(U_{\alpha})\}$ in $X$. Therefore, because we consider $K$ compact in $X$, $\{f(U_{\alpha})\}$ has a finite subcover $\{f(U_i)\}$, which we pull back to $Y$ and get a finite subcover $\{U_i\}$ in $Y$. The statement is proved.

Answer (score 2):

False. $X=K=[0,1]$ is compact but $K \cap A=A=(0,1)$ is non-compact.

It is true that compactness is inherited by closed subsets. Indeed, let $A\subseteq X$ be a closed set. If $\{U_i\}$ is an open cover of $A$, then $\{U_i\}\cup\{A^c\}$ is an open cover of $X$ and by compactness we may extract a finite subcover for $X$, which also gives a finite subcover for $A$.

Comment: Thanks. How about if we assume $A$ is not necessarily closed, but instead that $K\subseteq A$?

Comment: If $K \subseteq A$, then $K \cap A = K$ will be trivially compact because you assume it to be compact?

Comment: We assume it to be compact in the topology of $X$, but not in the induced topology on $A$.

Comment: So we would have to show that every open cover of $K$ (in the induced topology on $A$) has a finite subcover.

Comment: This does not matter. If $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$, then in your notation $(\tau_B)_A = \tau_A$. That is, a subspace of a subspace of $X$ is again a subspace of $X$.

Comment: In particular, compactness does not depend on the ambient space.

Comment: I'm confused. Certainly compactness depends on the topology. And the induced topology depends on the ambient space's topology by definition?

Comment: Yes, suppose I have the following situation: $K \subseteq A \subseteq X$  Then $K$ will be compact in $X$ if and only if it compact in $A$ (with the subspace topology inherited from $X$), as you can prove. This follows from the observations in my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, I just think there is some subtlety regarding which sets are open in which topologies. For example, in your answer, the $U_i$ may be open in $A$ but not in $X$, as long as we are considering the subspace topology.